# Painting over a transparent window in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, wm-paint

I wish to paint over a window created with the styles `WS_EX_TOPMOST|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT|WS_EX_LAYERED`, in the `WM_PAINT` message the window receives.

Can I do that? If not what can I do to draw an **animation** *(the content drawn is changed)* over a transparent (both visually and hit-transparent) window?

I an able to see the animation being drawn `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT|WS_EX_LAYERED` are not specified, but that doesn't achieve the goal as I want the window to be transparent.

Comment: [WS_EX_TRANSPARENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff700543.aspx): *"The window should not be painted until siblings beneath the window (that were created by the same thread) have been painted."* In other words: A window with this style is not automatically transparent, but allows you to implement transparency by ensuring, that siblings are rendered first. What you really need to post is the code that calls [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540.aspx).

Comment: Bonus reading: [Like the cake, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is a lie, or at least not the entire truth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/17/10378525.aspx).